# Capybara not finding signout link by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

For a rails app I'm currently working on I recently changed the design somewhat so that the signout link no longer has the anchor text "Sign out" but instead a glyphicon from twitter bootstrap. the html for link now looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
</a>
```

meanwhile my capybara test looks like this:

```
context "when not logged in" do

  it 'cannot create wikis' do
    @free_user = create(:user)
    login_as(@free_user, :scope => :user)

    click_link "Sign out"

    visit root_path
    expect(page).to_not have_link('Create wiki')
  end
end
```

Now that the text "Sign out" is no longer there, I need a new way to identify the link. Checking the documentation for capybara (or rather [this handy cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105)), it looks like I can supply *either* the text of the link or its id. So I tried giving it an id:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" id="signout" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
</a>
```

So now it's got an id of "signout" however when I make this change to the test, it still won't pass.

```
  1) Standard (free) User when not logged in cannot create wikis
     Failure/Error: click_link "signout"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "signout"
     # ./spec/features/standard_user_role_spec.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried making sure that I was still a logged in user in the test by creating and logging in the user as seen above and by adding a check that the html on the page contains Hello, since it says "Hello" and the name of the user when the user is logged in:

```
expect(page).to have_content('Hello')
```

This gave me another error that I don't understand:

```
  1) Standard (free) User when not logged in cannot create wikis
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Hello')
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"
     # ./spec/features/standard_user_role_spec.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So what could be going on here?

Full spec available [here](https://gist.github.com/e36e92c345f4c42ab543)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-add the text but hide it from all but screen readers:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" id="signout" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="sr-only">Sign out</span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
</a>
```

This also improves accessibility somewhat.

```
context "when not logged in" do

  it 'cannot create wikis' do
    @free_user = create(:user)
    login_as(@free_user, :scope => :user)

    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign out", visible: false 

    expect(page).to_not have_link('Create wiki')
  end
end
```

Note that we explicitly tell Capybara to look for hidden text with the `visible` option.

Comment: I really like this answer--it solves my problem and has the benefit of improving accessibility as well. Nice! However it still doesn't answer the question of why capybara wasn't finding the id in the first place, which I'm still curious about...

Comment: So I seem to have accidentally moved visit root_path to after the click_link--it wasn't finding anything because I hadn't landed on the page yet...

Comment: Yeah, I´ve had that happen to me several times as well. I like to use [`save_and_open_page`](https://coderwall.com/p/jsutlq/capybara-s-save_and_open_page-with-css-and-js) when capybara cannot find something I expect to be there.

Answer (score -1):

For the applications, which use `JS`, that means the request is being sent using for example `json` format, and is begin triggered by click on the link. (suppose the `HTML` markup is the same). It is useful the following call:

```
find('Sign Out', visible: false).trigger('click')
```

or by `id` (if you'll add it):

```
find(:css, "#sign-out", visible: false).trigger('click')
```

Comment: This is a bad general recommendation since it is not replicating what a user could do

Comment: @TomWalpole and how would you fix the post?

Comment: @TomWalpole in may the that was the only way to test click on link.

Comment: Don't generally search for invisible elements (i.e. No visible false since a user couldn't see it to interact), and don't use trigger generally since it avoids the side effects and other events around a users click.   As the comments on the answer show the reason it wasn't being found in this case was because it wasn't actually on the page

Comment: @TomWalpole you aren't correct, because the question was exatly to use the invisible control.

Comment: Please read the comments on the accepted answer - clicking the link by id wasn't working because the OP hadn't actually visited the page with the link on it, and on the real page the link wasn't invisible it had a glyph instead of text -- so once visiting the page clicking by id would work and also something like   click_link('', href: '/user/sign_out') would have worked too.   The immediate jump by people to use visible:false in Capybara is not good because it ends up testing things users couldn't actually do and not testing what they could do.

Comment: @TomWalpole For me `click_link('', href: '/user/sign_out')` hasn't work at all. I believe the visible link also wouldn't work. But, in some case I require just to click invisible links directly, to decrease time spent to tests run.

Comment: Then your tests aren't replicating user behavior and aren't really valid - If thats how you want to test fine, but it definitely should not be a recommended generality to others.

Comment: @TomWalpole > Then your tests
No, because it is enough a single test to cover the feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90344/discussion-between-tom-walpole-and--).